# Nodejs: Stringified Object not written to file on fs.writeFile()

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, filestream, stringify

I am trying to write the webpack config to a file. However the contents of the file are always empty everytime I do `fs.writeFile`.

```
module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => {
    fs.writeFile('test.txt', JSON.stringify(obj), err => { console.log(err); });
}
```

This writes the file but the contents of the file are empty. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: obj is undefined in your code sample

Comment: your code is working for me. any chance the program exit before it writes the data? how do you call this function?

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO - put anything in the object to see if it works for you

Comment: @Michael - I am calling this in the webpack ... Before Merging my Configs I wanted write the configs on the file.

Comment: i dont know a lot about webpack but is there any difference with fs.writeFileSync('test.txt', JSON.stringify(obj));

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO - I already tried `fs.writeFileSync` and that works. But not sure whats causing it not to work with writeFile

Answer (score 0):

it looks like callback functions are not working - must be related to imports contraints.

therefore, this works

```
module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => {
  let obj = {};
  fs.writeFileSync('test.txt', JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Also, according to documentation : https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/ promises should work.

```
module.exports = async (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => {
  let obj = {};
  await fs.promises.writeFile('test.txt', JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```